# Is it legal to seek someone out to make them violate a restraining order?

Tags: restraining-orders

A plot device I have seen on several TV shows is person A has filed a restraining order against person B, and then person A intentionally gets near person B to make person B have to run away to make sure they don't violate the restraining order. John Oliver does it to Ken Jeung in this clip: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qUDYH_5szo4&feature=youtu.be&t=14m6s

Is person A breaking any laws if they do this? Would this count as person B violating the order if they didn't back away?

Comment: Damn. I was expecting a clip from Last Week Tonight, demonstrating the dysfunctions and abuse potential of frivolous restraining orders. Instead, you picked something from an NBC sitcom. By the way, link's broken now.

Answer (score 3):

Restraining orders are a matter of state law and the technical answer will vary by jurisdiction. However, abusing a restraining order to harass someone is the kind of behavior that will make you look unreasonable to a judge (and unafraid of your abuser) and hurt you in subsequent actions before that judge, such as in a divorce or when you are seeking to extend the duration of that order. In addition, the court can issue a restraining order against you.

In theory, such abuse of an order may also make you liable for criminal or civil penalties related to the state's harassment or anti-stalking statutes, but you would need to review the law in the particular state. In practice, it is likely that the judge or commissioner reviewing a case will listen to the facts and tell you to knock it off, whether they put it in an order or not. Regardless of the particular outcome, it is just a bad idea. However, for an understanding of the law in a particular state, ask a lawyer admitted in that jurisdiction to advise you on the consequences of that course of action.